# Add to CSS calc on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, path, filepath

I am trying to make a nice scrolling effect with simple jquery. It is not working however. It works with the exact same code in a test environment.

The code seems to be loaded when I open the page, and there are no errors in console. I have no clue as to what could be causing this.

It works in codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzOKYM?editors=1111

SASS (uncompiled) and JS:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  youtubeVidScroll();
});


function youtubeVidScroll() {

  var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  $(".video-strip").css("background-position": "calc(50% - " + wScroll + "px) center");
}
```

```css
// SASS
.video-strip
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  position: absolute
  background:
  image: url(../images/video-strip.png)
  repeat: repeat-x
  size: 400%
  background-position: calc(50% - 0px) center
```

https://github.com/DatScreamer/Screamer-Portfolio

**EDIT:**

At this point I have removed everything from my files and only have what I have on codepen, yet it still does not work. I know now that it is not a problem with my javascript, but somewhere in between linking the JS and the browser reading it. I put a simple jquery thing in and it does not even work. (.hide())

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being `overflow: hidden` on `html, body` in the _base.sass, a file that is not much used as it is a personal boilerplate... Once that was removed it worked. I did not even remember adding overflow property to the _base.sass.

Thanks for the tips in the comments, straggly they where removed...

PS. I think this is a good question because for beginners at JS may not know that overflow prevents scrolling and other effects.